# Tracking price movements - percentage (multiplicative) vs nominal (additive) change

Tags: percentages

If I am tracking an asset like a stock (for example), then if it goes down 50% one day, to return to its previous price it would have to go up 100% (rather than 50%). I.e.: 1 * (1 - 50%) * (1 + 100%) = 1

On the other hand if you track nominal changes, the symmetry exists (e.g. 5 + 5 - 5) but you lose the intuitive scale of the movement.

Is there a better mathematical way to preserve the symmetry of addition/subtraction while maintaining the benefits of multiplication/division?

Answer (score 0):

I think the symmetry you are looking for is already there if you think of percentage change in terms of multiplication (and division) from the start.

Instead of calculating a $25\%$ increase in some quantity $Q$ by finding $25\%$ of $Q$ and adding it to $Q$, just multiply to compute $1.25Q$. To undo a $25\%$ increase you just divide by $1.25$, which is the same as multiplying by 
$1/1.25 = 0.8$.

Using this "multiply by $1 + $ percent change" technique it's easy to calculate successive increases and decreases and understand compound interest, exponential growth and  half lives.

Comment: Hmm, I'm more looking for a function where if you grow a number by 25 units and then contract it by 25 units you get what you started with, while the 25 units are proportionate to the size of the original number. Here either the function changes (multiplication vs division) or the numbers don't look symmetrical (1.25 vs 0.8)