# How to add percentage value by multiplication?

Tags: percentages

I'm studying the APL language and doing the exercises [here:](https://aplwiki.com/LearnApl/SimpleArithmetic) One of the questions is:

> b) Add 15% to each number in the list 14 5 78 145.

I tried this:

```
14 5 78 145 + (14 × 15 ÷ 100) (5 × 15 ÷ 100) (78 × 15 ÷ 100) (145 × 15 ÷ 100)
```

I get the correct results but this is ugly since I had to write each number. The better answer is given as:

```
14 5 78 145 × 1.15
```

I could not figure out how they got 1.15? How can 1.15 work for each different number? Can you help?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684019/tracking-price-movements-percentage-multiplicative-vs-nominal-additive-cha/2684036#2684036

Answer (score 1):

Given a number N the $15\%$ of that number is given by

$$\frac{15}{100}\times N=0.15\times N$$

then

$$N+0.15\times N=1.15 \times N$$

Comment: So for N=5, do we do this? 5/5 + (0.15 * 5) / 5 = (1.15 * 5) / 5

Comment: @zeynel For $N=5$ we have $5+5*0.15=5+0.75=5.75$.

Comment: how do we get 1 in 1.15? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @zeynel: “Add 15% to N” means “calculate N + (15% of N)”. The 1 in 1.15 comes from the first N in “N + (15% of N)”. To see that, $ N + (\text{15% of} N) = N + \frac {15} {100} × N = 1 × N + 0.15×N = (1 + 0.15)×N = 1.15×N $.